# Code signed apps on OS X Sierra 10.12 wont work old older macs, why?

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite, code-signing, osx-mountain-lion, osx-gatekeeper

I have 'identified developer' certificates from Apple.

I have signed my app using Sierra via the commands line as my app is outside of xcode, signatures validate on Sierra as from an identified developer.

Testing on Sierra allows installation when the security settings are:

'Allow allocations downloaded from: Mac App Store and identified developers'.

Testing on OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion gives the error ".app is damaged" as attached.[Gatekeeper Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wiJ2.jpg) This error occurs when the security settings are:

'Allow allocations downloaded from: Mac App Store and identified developers'.

Changing the security settings to

'Allow allocations downloaded from: Anywhere'.

Allows the app to be installed just fine, so I am sure that the file is valid.

Why does an app validate on newer macs only.

I also tried signing the app on 10.8. In this scenario 10.8 accepts the app as from an identified developer but 10.12 does not, the exact opposite.

Answer (score 1):

10.8 does not support validating certificates using SHA256, codesign on 10.12 used SHA256.